How can I get delta time between frames for frame_change_post/frame_change_pre handlers?
I am editing an addon that modifies bones' rotation and depends on delta time between frames. After one frame switches to another one, the step function of addon should receive delta time in seconds between current frame and previous frame, however Blender API website states that both frame_change_pre and frame_change_post handlers always have scene.frame_current value set to current frame. Right now my handler looks like this:
@persistent
def frame_change_post(scene):
    """
    Called when timeline frame was changed after all Blender's updates.
    """
    step(scene, scene.render.fps_base / scene.render.fps)

Instead of actual delta time it uses 1 second divided by current FPS (scene.render.fps / scene.render.fps_base), so if I have 60 FPS and instantly switch, for example, from frame 1 to frame 10, it will still only get delta time of 0.017 instead of 0.15.
If frame_change_post is not the right handler to use in this situation, please recommend me the one that will suit it.
